# Reading CDATA tag value from XML using xmllint without any extra information in shell script

Tags: xml, shell, xmllint

How can read cdata tag information from xml without any extra information

test.xml

```
<EncodingKeys>
    <Streaming> 
        <![CDATA[54G91A8?s7^F97C]Fyj*8&kR2eU+HNg!]]>
    </Streaming>
    <Uploads> 
        <![CDATA[&^%&^*vsfgsdfEw#z2etVCTSN@Sb!F2]]>
    </Uploads>
</EncodingKeys>
```

test.sh

```
Streamingkey="$(echo "cat /EncodingKeys/Streaming/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell test.xml | sed '1d;$d')"
Uploadskey="$(echo "cat /EncodingKeys/Uploads/text()" | xmllint --nocdata --shell test.xml | sed '1d;$d')"

echo $Streamingkey
echo $Uploadskey
```

actual output:

```
54G91A8?s7^F97C]Fyj*8&amp;kR2eU+HNg!
&amp;^%&amp;^*vsfgsdfEw#z2etVCTSN@Sb!F2
```

expected output:

```
54G91A8?s7^F97C]Fyj*8&kR2eU+HNg!
&^%&^*vsfgsdfEw#z2etVCTSN@Sb!F2
```

why i am getting `&amp;` in place of `&`. and i can see lenght id variables also more.

Could some one help me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Use xml_grep !

Prepare a test file

```
    $cat test.xml
    <EncodingKeys>
        <Streaming> 
            <![CDATA[54G91A8?s7^F97C]Fyj*8&kR2eU+HNg!]]>
        </Streaming>
        <Uploads> 
            <![CDATA[&^%&^*vsfgsdfEw#z2etVCTSN@Sb!F2]]>
        </Uploads>
    </EncodingKeys>
```

**For 'Streaming' use**

```
    $ xml_grep --text_only 'Streaming' test.xml
```

to get

```
    54G91A8?s7^F97C]Fyj*8&kR2eU+HNg!
```

**For 'Uploads' use**

```
    $ xml_grep --text_only 'Uploads' test.xml
```

to get

```
    &^%&^*vsfgsdfEw#z2etVCTSN@Sb!F2
```